# Sqlite Query not working with MAX keyword

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, sqlite-net

I must be missing something because all I'm trying to do is return a MAX(ID) value within a given table.  Please look at the following screenshot:

[screenshot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aly2tBjDTFD-hagWKmwJoTBaPKaL9A)

A) Shows all of the data that exists in the table.

B) Shows the query I can run using the SQLite Expert tool.

C) Shows what the query returns using the tool.

D) Shows the query I'm writing in C#

After running D I get 1 row back with a value of 0 every single time.  What gives?

Comment: Please post your code as text editing your question and add more context around that single line. db.Query is a method common to many ORM frameworks. It is not clear which one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is loose at **types**.

You can use `ExecuteScalar`;

```
var max= db.ExecuteScalar<int>("query");
```

or you can create a class (maybe you have already);

```
class Example{
     public int Id{get;set;}
}

var max = db.Query<Example>("query");
```

`max[0].Id` will gave you 1001000

Hope helps,